# Formatting and filtering query results by date from Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am using Python to pull data from a BigQuery database. The data from the database has years of data, but I only need the last two years. Furthermore, the data in the "bill_date" column isn't formatted correctly (i.e. August 8th 2020 is "20200806") and is an int64 dtype.

In a SQL query, how do I pull just the last two years of data ending in the last day of the previous month? So in this case I want just data from August 1st, 2018 - July 31st, 2020. Any help or documentation would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the date to get the appropriate end points and convert to an `int64`:

```
where bill_date < cast(format_date('%Y%m%d', date_trunc(current_date, month)) as int64) and
      bill_date >= cast(format_date('%Y%m%d', date_add(date_trunc(current_date, month), interval -24 month)) as int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT <columns>
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', FORMAT('%i', bill_date)) 
  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
  AND DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

You can refactor above if you want it to be less verbose

```
#standardSQL
SELECT <columns>
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)]) month_start
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', FORMAT('%i', bill_date)) 
  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(month_start, INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
  AND DATE_SUB(month_start, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```